# Set a message for a RuleSet fails in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

It's possible in FluentValidation to have a specific error message for a RuleSet?

Something like:

```
RuleSet("LoginInformation", () =>
{
    RuleFor(m => m.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress();
    RuleFor(m => m.Password).NotEmpty();
}); // I thought I can add a WithMessage here...
```

That should show a single error message if any of the Rules fail.

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION**

It is impossible to set error message to `RuleSet` directly without changing FluentValidation sources, but you can collect your rules in special list, and set same error message in loop:

```
RuleSet("LoginInformation", () =>
{
    var loginRules = new List<IRuleBuilderOptions<CredentialsModel, object>>
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress(),
        RuleFor(m => m.Password).NotEmpty()
    };

    foreach (var rule in rules)
    {
        // this overload chosen just to show, that all possibilities to set error message still available
        rule.WithMessage("An error occured. Additional information: {0}, {1}", (model, value) => value, (model, value) => model.Email);
    }
});
```

There are only 2 [cascade mode options](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/Configuring-a-Validator#setting-the-cascade-mode), and you can't tell validator to stop *all rules* on first failure of one, so you need to take only first error from validation result and remove other same errors. For this purpose you can override `AbstractValidator`:

```
public class SingleErrorValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context)
    {
        var result = base.Validate(context);

        if (result.IsValid)
            return result;

        var singleErrorList = new List<ValidationFailure> { result.Errors.First() };
        var singleErrorResult = new ValidationResult(singleErrorList);

        return singleErrorResult;
    }
}
```

**ADVANCED SOLUTION:**

If you forked FluentValidation and can modify the source code in your solution, then you can make reuseable approach for common error message and add next `RuleSet` method overload in `AbstractValidator` class (you can't use extension method or inheritance because important fields have private modifier):

```
public void RuleSet(string ruleSetName, Func<List<IRuleBuilderOptions<T, object>>> function, Action<IRuleBuilderOptions<T, object>> writeRuleMessage)
{
    ruleSetName.Guard("A name must be specified when calling RuleSet.");
    function.Guard("A ruleset definition must be specified when calling RuleSet.");

    using (nestedValidators.OnItemAdded(r => r.RuleSet = ruleSetName))
    {
        var list = function();

        foreach (var rule in list)
        {
            writeRuleMessage(rule);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `RuleSet` next way:

```
RuleSet("LoginInformation", () =>
{
    var rules = new List<IRuleBuilderOptions<B, object>>()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().EmailAddress(),
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty()
    };

    return rules;
}, (rule) => 
{ 
    rule.WithMessage("An error occured");
}); // still can use another overloads, that allow access to model and validated properties
```

**CONCLUSION**

Both solutions are able to work, but I recommend to use 1-st due to KISS principle.